# Error when attempting to parse Locale Numberformatted String and cast to BigDecimal

Tags: java, parsing, locale, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal ("2.99");

Locale locale = new Locale ("en", "US");

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurencyInstance(locale);

String formattedPrice = numberFormat(num);

BigDecimal newPrice = (BigDecimal) numberFormat.parse(formattedPrice);

System.out.println(newPrice);
```

I encounter an error that says "class java.lang.Double can not be cast to class java.math.BigDecimal".

As a newbie in the world of java, I need a "down-to-earth", clear explanation that would help me understand what is going on, not just a solution. Going through the online course at Oracle says this should work but isn't. (I know I could probably use the wrapper "Double" instead ), But I am looking mostly for an explanation. Thanks

Comment: Any comments on this one?

Comment: The line `numberFormat(num)` makes no sense and can't compile either ... could you please post the code that you *actually* compiled and ran? A [minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you will.

Comment: Basically a `DecimalFormat` will return a `BigDecimal` there **iff** `isParseBigDecimal()` returns `true`.